# Finding the size of a pointer

Tags: c

```
printf("pointer: %d\n", sizeof(*void));
```

This line results in a syntax error because of the *.  What should I do to get it to work?

Comment: Note that you should be using `"%zu"` to print `size_t` types (i.e. the values returned by `sizeof`) rather than `"%d"`. It's a pedantic difference, but you wouldn't want to see a -3 element array, would you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are currently trying to find out the size that is at address void. If you are looking to find the size of a void pointer perhaps try: sizeof(void*) instead.

```
printf("pointer: %zu\n", sizeof(void*));
```

should do what you want. Use %zu and not %d as the pointer is an unsigned value and not a decimal.

Edit: Something else that I just thought of for the first time, is %zu compiler dependent? Do we need to do things differently on 32bit or 64bit architecture?

Answer (score 6):

```
printf("pointer: %d\n", sizeof(void*));
```